# TV Channel Playing for JWplayer Test using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I need to automate a TV channel playing web-application http:\wherever.tv to test if a Channel is successfully playing or failed to play. I have the **Selenium IDE script** for Channel playing.How can i handle the case if a channel fails to play. The Channel uses the `jwplayer`.How How can i show the Channel failure message for JWPlayer.

Below is the code for playing the Channel.

```
   public class Untitled {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private String baseUrl;
    private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
    private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "http://wherever.tv/";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Test
    public void testUntitled() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/index2.jsf");
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("SIGN IN")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("login:txtUserName")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("login:txtUserName")).sendKeys("testm1");
    driver.findElement(By.id("login:txtPassword")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("login:txtPassword")).sendKeys("111111");
    driver.findElement(By.id("login:cmbSumbit")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//img[@title='(On Air) Play - This channel will work on     TV'])[7]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//img[@title='(On Air) Play - This channel will NOT work   on TV'])[4]")).click();
  }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
      fail(verificationErrorString);
     }
    }

    private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
    try {
      driver.findElement(by);
      return true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
      return false;
    }
    }

    private String closeAlertAndGetItsText() {
    try {
      Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
      if (acceptNextAlert) {
        alert.accept();
      } else {
        alert.dismiss();
      }
      return alert.getText();
    } finally {
      acceptNextAlert = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question i assume, you need a way to display or find whether an error message is displayed. If that is the case you need to use Assert statement

The following statement is clicking the error code.

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//img[@title='(On Air) Play - This channel will NOT work   on TV'])[4]")).click();
```

you can use an assert() for this purpose, as Assert.assertEquals() or any other appropriate assert() for comparing this value.

exg

```
String expMsg  "'(On Air) Play - This channel will NOT work   on TV'";
Assert.assertEquals(expMsg,driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//img[@title='(On Air) Play - This channel will NOT work   on TV'])[4]")).getText();
```

A  more correct xpath will help you in identifying pass as well as fail status.